# Android Nearby.MESSAGES_API to just detect beacons

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-nearby

I was earlier using the AltBeacon Library for detecting beacons and it works perfectly without any problems. 
Then i came across 
https://developers.google.com/beacons/overview?hl=en

Which suggest
The Google Proximity Beacon API can be used to register any beacon that supports one of the following specifications: (They mentioned register may be i was mistaken to assume it may detect as well)

- Eddystone
- iBeacon
- AltBeacon

So i was interested and started using the subscribe API after creating the Project in Google Console and using the googleApiClient along with Nearby.MESSAGES_API and strategy BLE_ONLY for detecting beacons. And was unsuccessful.

After that reading the API docs completely (should have done before investing time) it mentions

*In order to work with Google APIs, beacons must first be provisioned with some initial settings (namespace ID, instance ID, frame format, and so on), and then registered using the Google Proximity Beacon API.*

So does this mean i have to compulsorily configure the beacons individually before using just any random beacon with my app to detect and get message? It might seem obvious i just don't want to go with a custom 3rd party implementation like AltBeacon if GooglePlayService.Nearby_Message_API supports listening to any beacon.

In case its possible and if someone has already tried just listening to beacons enter and exit events without the need to configure do let me know i can share the code and take it forward. Or i should leave the Nearby API and go back to good old AltBeacon.

BR,
Jayshil